# java negative lookbehind regex bug?

Tags: java, regex

My java @windows is:

```
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Code

```
Pattern.compile(".+(?<!(xxx|idea|perforator|pycharm|s).*)").matcher("xxx").matches() //returns TRUE while it should return FALSE
Pattern.compile(".+(?<!(xxx|idea|perforator|pycharm|s).*)").matcher("perforator").matches() //returns FALSE
```

Looks like negative lookbehind fails if string is smaller than 8 chars.

Is it bug or do I misunderstand something about regex?

Comment: What do you want to do? Both lines should match, as the first `.+` will backtrack till the lookbehind succeeds.

Comment: @Qtax the java matcher's eternally question-causing `matches()` method is only a success if the expression captures the entire input string as a match.

Answer (score 4):

Lookbehinds in Java cannot have variable-length things like `.*`, only things like alternations and finite repetitions.

More Information: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match substrings that do not contain some words (as a part of a bigger expression) you can use:

```
(?s:(?!xxx|idea|perforator|pycharm|s).)*
```

If that is the only thing you are doing, just invert the result of the match:

```
xxx|idea|perforator|pycharm|s
```